# Hexo list child categoies

Tags: hexo

I have a news site and news articles are broken down into `country` and then `city`.

Is there away that a person can click on Canada to see all news from Canada and then see all the cities in Canada is the sidebar? Like the visual below:

[image]

This is what I have as my `md` file

```
- [Canada, Toronto]
```

When I use:

```
<%- list_categories() %>
```

I see all the categories listed and their children so:

```
Canada
 - Toronto
 - Ontario
 - Vancouver

Poland
 - Warsaw
 - Gdansk
```

But only want to show Canadian cities in the sidebar if a person clicks Canada, and only see Polish cities if they clicked on Poland.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.categories` to get the categories for the current post or page.

Then you could extract the country with `post.categories.first()` and use that value to filter the things you are getting from `<%- list_categories() %>`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @klugjo but I get a `Unhandled rejection ReferenceError:` when I try this :-/

Comment: Do you have a link to your repo or can you post more of the source code ?

Comment: Unfortunately I am still setting it up, the only code I used was `<%- list_categories() %>` but then tried `<%- post.categories.first() %>`

Comment: which page are you in ? Is it index ? archives ? post ?

Comment: I tried it on Archive as it's the page I have the sidebar on. Sorry but I am new to Hexo...

Comment: <%- page.category %> should print out the current archive category. <%- site.categories %> should give you access to the full list of categories for your site.

Comment: oh I tried this and still not how I wanted it, so just to confirm there is no way to get it to be like the image I posted above? I can show all categories but wanted to only show child categories when you are on a parent category page.